# Detecting a mail was sent using swift mailer in current scope

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm building functional tests for a Symfony2 app and need to know when an email was sent but not from an api request. (This link **is not** what i'm looking for: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html)

The flow of the application is the following:

- User create a personalized video
- A flattening request (to create the final video) is sent to a GNASH server via a queue
- Once GNASH is done it posts a message to another queue
- We process the queue using a daemon
- While processing the responses which can arrive anytime, the system dispatches a VideoFlatteningCompleteEvent
- This even is caught and sends an email to the owner to tell him the video is ready.

My goal:

- Dispatch the VideoFlatteningCompleteEvent by myself since it takes too many steps to reproduce the workflow event with well forged tests (easy)
- Collect the mails sent or find a way to intercept the mail to validate it was sent once the event is dispatched.

Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution after some digging. Using a plugin for swiftmailer, i'm able to collect the emails sent using the Send event. This way, i can, on the fly, see what emails were sent and not. Probably something similar is used for the DataCollector in Symfony2's profiler.

Comment: Swiftmailer plugins are a good option. Alternatively you can 1) spool the messages to disk and read them (they are serialize message objects). 2) Although you say you didn't want to make API requests, I would still recommend you check out mailcatcher.me. I use this in larger acceptance testing scenarios where you might not be coupled directly into the application and may only observe side effects.

Comment: Your serialization to disk is an interresting option but mailcatcher seems to be only for visual feedback. In a fully tested app (functional and unit) this cannot be used except for debugging purposes...

Comment: mailcatcher provides a really nice API for automated testing, actually. Check out their website homepage and scroll down to API.